# (html/css) button not following scale of the site

Tags: html, css, button, scale

So uhm I am VERY new here at StackOverflow and html/css in general.

---

So my problem is this: When visiting the website, the button called "Zeig mir mehr!" isn't scaled properly with the size of the browser. To get you an idea of what I mean here are some screenshots: [This is how it looks like with the first pixel ratio (and how it should look like from the positioning)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyNet.jpg)

now to the broken part: [different pixel ratio, button overlaps with text/animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXjtz.jpg)

---

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
            <span class="text1">Kevnkkm /Startseite </span>
            <span class="text2">Willkommen!</span>
            <h1>THIS PORTFOLIO WEBSITE WHICH IS USED FOR PERSONAL USAGE ONLY IS STILL HEAVILY UNDER CONSTRUCTION!</h1>
        </div>
        <section class="banner">
            <div class="button" style="top: 500px">
                <a href="#content" class="btn">Zeig mir mehr!</a>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and this is the stylesheet:

```
.button{
    top: 58%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
```

Thanks in advance! (Also sorry for the facepalms I might cause xd)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post the CSS code for the button?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: added meaningful code to the problem, thanks for reaching out and notifing me about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you are using a set pixel amount for the button. Ideally, a button like that would be after the text in HTML so it would move with the text, instead of using `position: absolute`.

You should move the button element into the `container` element after the red `h1`. You can then replace the CSS for `.button` for a `margin-top: 32px`